# Getting Office 365 groups in sharepoint CSOM with powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

I've created an security group through Sharepoint Administrator portal, let's name it "**group1**". and I have a website, with a list and in that list there is a person/group column field, let's name it "**PersonGroupColumn**".

When I add a new item to my list, i can find "**group1**" when I type into "PersongroupColumn". Although, what I want to do is to set up a *powershell script* that updates all the items of my list with "**group1**" in "**PersonGroupColumn**"

Here my starting script:

```
# Get Start Time
$startDTM = (Get-Date)

# Global variables
$User = ""
$Pwd = ""
$SiteURL = ""

# Functions

function addUser
{
    param([string]$DisplayName,[string]$Group)
    $d=New-Object PSObject
    $d | Add-Member -Name DisplayName -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $DisplayName
    $d | Add-Member -Name Group -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $Group
    return $d
}

#Libraries
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SharePoint.Client') > $null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SharePoint') > $null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('MsOnline') > $null

# Password Init
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $Pwd -AsPlainText -Force

# Connection to Office 365
$Creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $Password)

connect-msolservice -credential $Creds


# Gathering groups and members
$array = @()
$Groups = Get-MsolGroup
foreach($Group in $Groups)
{
    $Members = Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $Group.ObjectId

    $line = New-Object psobject
    foreach($Member in $Members)
    {
        $array += AddUser $Member.DisplayName $Group.DisplayName
    }
}

# Connection to sharepoint Online
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User, $Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

# gathering the list
$Web = $Context.Web
$List = $Web.Lists.GetByTitle('Rapport de visite')
$Context.Load($Web)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$Query = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
$Items = $List.GetItems($Query)
$Context.Load($Items)

foreach($Item in $Items)
{

    $AffectedGroup = ""
    $Item['Groupes'] = ""

    foreach($Member in $array)
    {
        if($Item['Author'].LookupValue -eq $Member.DisplayName) {
            $AffectedGroup = $Member.Group
        }
    }

    if($Item["Groupes"] -ne $AffectedGroup) {
        $Item['Groupes'] = $AffectedGroup + ";"
        $Item.Update()
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    }

}

# Get End Time
$endDTM = (Get-Date)

# Echo Time elapsed
"Elapsed Time: $(($endDTM-$startDTM).totalseconds) seconds"
```

It seems like I need to create a **fieldUserValue** object and push it into the item's field, but I need the **LookupId** of the group and I don't know where to get it.

Some help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!